# How to export the data of a Mysql table including the values of referenced ID's of another table

Tags: mysql, database, csv, export

//I have updated the question to hopefully clarify things better as I'm still at a loss. I got some very much appreciated help but I can't get it to work yet//

I'm still new at this, new here as well, so I hope I'll explain it clearly enough. If not, please let me know.

1. I have 2 tables   Table 1 "students" , Table 2 'Mixed data"

[image: tables]

2. Table 1 "students" has the columns "ID", "Name" and "Experience"

   In the column "Experience" the fields refer to data from Table 2 "Mixed Data"
3. I am able to export the data of the table "students" to CSV

*I use for this export the following query*

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM students;
```

4. In the file "results.csv"  the data of the ID's will be the ID's and not the real value/name

I like to be able to export the data into CSV and have the values and not the ID reference in the exported file.

**Current export result**

ID  |   Name      | Experience
1   |   Gary      | 5
2   |   Mary      | 4

the number "4" and "5" in Experience refers to the id in table 2 "Mixed data"

**Result I like to have in the export .csv"**

ID  |   Name      | Experience
1   |   Gary      | Super experienced
2   |   Mary      | Lots of experience

In this export of the CSV the experience field contains now the real values, being "Super experience", "Lots of experience"

Is it possible to export the data of a table including the values of referenced ID's of another table
and if yes, how should I adjust my query.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem.
Just add desired table to the SELECT statement, for example -

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name, e.Experience FROM students s
JOIN experience e ON s.ID = e.ID
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.

I tried it but I'm afraid I  got an error, saying 

check mysql version for the right syntax to use near '.name, e.experience FROM dive_sites_copy s
JOIN experience e ON s.id = e.id
INTO' at line 1

I probably should have mentioned the Mysql information as well, sorry for that.

I use Mysql 5.1.73 on a Centos server
===

Comment: Getting back to the export query

You mentioned to "add the desired table to the SELECT statement."

In my case I like to select the value of an item in another table, combine that with the data from the main table and then export.

Q1a. In your example, "JOIN experience .." is "experience" the name of the other table?
Q1b. Or is it the name of field name of the Item in the other table.

Yes, I'm still confused I notice myself.

And is there another query I can try

Thanks again

Comment: About syntax error - comma was missed. About query, firstly, write a query that returns result you want. Or show your tables.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm getting closer but still got an error. It now tells me "ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected"    What do I miss (a lot I guess:)

Comment: Execute USE statement to set current database. Or use full object names, e.g.: SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name

Comment: Sorry, it's not ok yet, I'll will rewrite my question and hopefully I can add screenshots in order to clarify

Comment: rewritten the question and updated with a screenshot